# How do I find where a line intersects an axis-aligned box where at least one point of the line is always inside of this box?

Tags: c#, math, vector, 3d, constraints

I have a data type representing the maximum forces that can be applied per-axis to a machine in a game I'm making. This data type individually stores six axes -- X, Y, and Z, both positive and negative separately. This is used to define the maximum forces the device can apply in a given direction in 3D space. Since all parts that can apply force to this machine are axis-aligned (and by extension, can only apply force on one or more world-space normals), this does a perfect job of representing its limits.

Using this information, I construct a sort of bounding box. This bounding box is intended to constrain the amount of force that is required to move the machine into a smaller value representing what the machine can actually output.

My current method is to create this virtual bounding box from this data and see where my required force (visualized as a line segment where the first point is the origin of 3D space and the second point is the required force vector itself) intersects at least one of the faces on this virtual rectangular prism. I haven't quite gotten this method working due to some issues understanding how to pick apart this problem on my end, which is part of what I aim to remedy by asking this question. The bounding box always contains the origin of 3D space, but the origin of the box itself is not guaranteed to be equal to the origin of 3D space.

I think this box analogy is the best way to go so far, given that my limited force is best represented as where a line intersects this virtual box. Is there a better way to constrain a point within a box in the manner I need *without* simply constraining it per-axis? Here's the constants of the problem:

- The origin of the line segment representing my force will always be equal to the origin of 3D space.

  - As a result, the combined direction * magnitude of the line segment representing force will always be equal to the force itself.
- The origin of 3D space will **never** be outside of this virtual box.

I think I have the right idea, but it just feels far too complicated and I think there's a lot of stuff I can cut out to make this calculation easier, but the issue is that I'm not quite certain of where to start to make this as clean and efficient as possible, let alone the best way to actually solve this problem.

Here's the code I've tried.

```cs
public Vector3f ConstrainedWithinScaled(Vector3f value) {
    // Vector3f is a simple class that contains x, y, z, basic arithmetic operators (*/+-), Magnitude/Normalized properties, and Dot/Cross methods.
    // The code that this method exists in is a class called DualVector3f which is the class described above. It contains properties PosX, PosY, PosZ, NegX, NegY, and NegZ -- All of these properties have positive values as they describe magnitude on that specific face.

    if (IsInBounds(value)) {
        // The input value is already within the constraints of the virtual box.
        return value;
    }

    // Get all intersections
    // The first returned intersection that resides on this box's surface is correct.
    // Only in cases where the point reside on a corner or edge will result in multiple of these conditions being true, however in these cases the returned point will be identical in all 2 or 3 cases.
    Vector3f center = Center;
    Vector3f size = Size;
    // Cache these so that I don't calculate them every single time.
    // These are calculated from the minimum/maximum coordinates to create the center of the virtual box and the size of the virtual box respectively.
    // public Vector3f Size => Negative + Positive; (Negative and Positive both only have positive components, as outlined up top)
    // public Vector3f Center => Positive - (Size / 2); (Positive is always the maximum)
    // As should be evident, Positive is composed of PosX, PosY, and PosZ
    // Likewise, Negative is composed of NegX, NegY, and NegZ

    Vector3f topIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), center + new Vector3f(0, size.y, 0));
    if (topIntersection.y == PosY) return topIntersection;
    Vector3f bottomIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), center - new Vector3f(0, size.y, 0));
    if (bottomIntersection.y == -NegY) return bottomIntersection;
    Vector3f leftIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(-1, 0, 0), center - new Vector3f(size.x, 0, 0));
    if (leftIntersection.x == -NegX) return leftIntersection;
    Vector3f rightIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), center + new Vector3f(size.x, 0, 0));
    if (rightIntersection.x == PosX) return rightIntersection;
    Vector3f frontIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), center + new Vector3f(0, 0, size.z));
    if (frontIntersection.z == PosZ) return frontIntersection;
    Vector3f backIntersection = IntersectPoint(value, new Vector3f(0, 0, -1), center - new Vector3f(0, 0, size.z));
    if (backIntersection.z == -NegZ) return backIntersection;

    return new Vector3f(); // Fallback. This should theoretically never occur under any condition, so this simply satisfies the need to return.
}

// This was derived from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_intersection_of_a_line_with_a_plane#C.23 and omits the "rayOrigin" parameter as this is always a zero vector.
private static Vector3f IntersectPoint(Vector3f dirWithMag, Vector3f planeNormal, Vector3f planeCenter) {
    Vector3f diff = -planeCenter;
    float prod1 = diff.Dot(planeNormal);
    float prod2 = dirWithMag.Dot(planeNormal);
    float prod3 = prod1 / prod2;
    return dirWithMag * -prod3;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to provide the relevant sections of your code, so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: @Hayden Good point. I've made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to solve this problem is to take the vector and find which component is furthest out of bounds. After I find this component, I divide *all* components by the percentage representing how far out of bounds it is, which scales everything down to be within my box. This satisfies the solution because this places the point on the boundary of my box.

Here's the code that does it:

```cs
public Vector3f ConstrainedWithinScaled(Vector3f value) {
    if (IsInBounds(value)) {
        // The input value is already within the constraints of the virtual box.
        return value;
    }

    float factorX = 1;
    float factorY = 1;
    float factorZ = 1;
    if (value.x > PosX) {
        factorX = value.x / PosX;
    } else if (value.x < -NegX) {
        factorX = value.x / -NegX;
    }
    if (value.y > PosY) {
        factorY = value.y / PosY;
    } else if (value.y < -NegY) {
        factorY = value.y / -NegY;
    }
    if (value.z > PosZ) {
        factorZ = value.z / PosZ;
    } else if (value.z < -NegZ) {
        factorZ = value.z / -NegZ;
    }

    float largestFactor = Mathf.Max(factorX, factorY, factorZ);

    // Catch case: Box has zero size.
    if (largestFactor == 0) return Vector3f.Zero;

    return value / largestFactor;
}
```